# Clean up a referenced library's memory on runtime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, memory, memory-leaks

Sometimes you need to use a particular third-party library, like in my case, one that loads up PowerPoints and allows the user to modify them in code. We discovered that this particular library has some memory leaks, but we would still like to use it because these leaks only occur in one particular scenario that occurs very rarely. You can see objects lying around despite trying to dispose all references to them, and despite having these objects go out of scope, and despite having manually invoked garbage collection. For sure, this library creates leaks. Our application is single-threaded.

Now, that being said, I am wondering if there is any way to clean up all memory that the library has used during runtime. Are there any ways to unload and reload the DLL that might cause all memory allocations from that library to be cleared, or anything that we can do at runtime at all to clean the memory that this third party library uses and then potentially reload the library in our application?

Comment: Use it via a new AppDomain (which can be explicitly unloaded) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could investigate loading the referenced library inside a custom `AppDomain`; an app-domain is a unit of isolation *inside* a process - and can be unloaded. It does, however, require you to do some communications between the two app-domains (the default domain and the hosted domain); `MarshalByRefObject` is the easiest trick there.

Alternatively: just use an entire separate process for this work. On windows, creating a process is *relatively* expensive, but not so expensive that you should never do it. Shutting down the process when done is the equivalent of nuking it from orbit. You can always re-spawn another process later.

There is an entire series of "How to" topics about `AppDomain` [linked from MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain(v=vs.110).aspx)